# Strpos with both integer and word

Tags: php, strpos

I'm stuck. Ignore the top line, no use for date yet, but will be using in a bit. Having issues primarily with this line:

```
  if(strpos($line, $extension) !== false and (preg_match('#\d#',$line !== false))){
```

I'm trying to do is that if a domain name ($line) is a .com and has no numbers then echo it. All of the preg_replace and strlen seems to be working, but I can't get it to only perform the way I need. I need to put the preg_match outside of the <=40 rule as it may be causing confusion?

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$extension = '.com';
$lines = file('PoolDeletingDomainsList.txt');

echo "<b>4 Letter premiums for ". date("n/j/Y") .":</b><br />";

foreach($lines as $line)

if(strlen($line)<=40) {

{
  // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
  if(strpos($line, $extension) !== false and (preg_match('#\d#',$line !== false))){
    $line = preg_replace('/12:00:00 AM,AUC\b/','<br />', $line);
    $line = preg_replace('/,9\/28\/2013/', '', $line);
    echo $line;
  }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: `I need ot put the preg_match outside of the <=40 rule as it may be causing confusion` -- not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Not sure whether or not it will make a difference if  I put it above the if(strlen($line)<=40) section as it's own if statement.

Comment: Is the above code not working as you expected? What are the issues?

Comment: It either returns nothing at all or .com domains with numbers. The only thing I change is the !==false to == false on the end of the preg_match()

Comment: Did this issue get resolved? If so, please mark one of the answers correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Return Values

preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

[Manual preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
  if(strpos($line, $extension) !== false and (preg_match('#\d#',$line) !== false))){
    $line = preg_replace('/12:00:00 AM,AUC\b/','<br />', $line);
    $line = preg_replace('/,9\/28\/2013/', '', $line);
    echo $line;
  }
```

replace with

```
if ((false !== strpos($line, $extension)) && (1 === preg_match('#\d#',$line))){
    $line = preg_replace('/12:00:00 AM,AUC\b/','<br />', $line);
    $line = preg_replace('/,9\/28\/2013/', '', $line);
    echo $line;
}
```

This will check if $line contains .com and has numbers (otherwise those preg_replace would have nothing to work with).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what seemed to work for me.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$extension = '.com';
$lines = file('PoolDeletingDomainsList.txt');

echo "<b>4 Letter premiums for ". date("n/j/Y") .":</b><br />";

foreach($lines as $line)

if(strlen($line)<=36) {

{
  // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
  $line = preg_replace('/12:00:00 AM,AUC\b/','<br />', $line);
  $line = preg_replace('/,9\/28\/2013/', '', $line);

  if ((false !== strpos($line, $extension)) && (0 === preg_match('#\d#',$line)) && (0 === preg_match('/-/', $line))){
    echo $line;
  }
}
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) documentation:

> `preg_match()` returns `1` if the pattern matches given subject, 0`` if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

So, according to your current condition, the `if` statement will evaluate to `TRUE` if `preg_match` returns any value that's not `FALSE` (which includes `1` and `0`). And `preg_match` returns `1` if a match is found, so all your domains will pass the condition and echoed.

To fix the error, change your `if` statement to:

```
if(strpos($line, $extension) !== false && !preg_match('#\d#',$line)) {
```

Answer (score -1):

So you're searching for .com domains that have no numbers in it ("premium domains").

```
<?php

$lines = array(
    'example.com',
    'exa13mple.com',
    'domain.org',
    'google.com',
    '37signals.com'
);

foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $matches = array();
    $isComDomain = preg_match('/\w+\\.com/', $line, $matches);
    $hasNoNumbers = !empty($matches) ? preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+\\.com$/', $matches[0]) : false;

    if ($isComDomain && $hasNoNumbers) {
        print $matches[0] . "\n";
    }
}
```

The isComDomain is a boolean telling if it found a [word characters].com from the line. And if it found, it stores the found domain name in $matches[0].

Then the hasNoNumbers is a boolean telling if the .com domain name contained only chars from a-z and A-Z. You may wish to include "-" in the regex if you allow dashes.

Comment: Could the person, who downvoted my answer, explain the reason for the downvote?